# Detect change to user_meta and retrieve old and new values

Tags: hooks, user-meta

I want to track when a certain piece of user meta is changed in the admin, and then perform an action. I thought I found the correct hook for it (from https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update), but when I use this code:

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update', 10, 2 );

function my_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
    error_log(print_r($old_user_data,true));
}
```

My error log does not show the user meta that I am changing, only values from the main wp_users table and a bunch of capabilities. How can I grab the previously changed user_meta value (or detect a changed user_meta value) when a profile is saved in the admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I needed to use the `insert_user_meta` filter, not an action hook. And then I ALSO needed a combo of `get_user_meta` (to get the old data) and `$_POST` to get the value being changed to. Putting it all together, here is my final code to find when a particular `user_meta` field (in my case created with ACF) changes from one value to another:

```
add_filter( 'insert_user_meta', function( $meta, $user, $update ) {
  if( true !== $update ) return $meta; // if not an update (b/c it is a create) do nothing
if(is_admin()) { // check if we are in admin not front end
  $old_meta = get_user_meta( $user->ID );
  if( $old_meta['verified_member'][0] !== $_POST['acf']['field_5ad4eecd7564b'] ) {
    error_log("verified_member was modified from " . $old_meta['verified_member'][0] . " to " . $_POST['acf']['field_5ad4eecd7564b']);
  }}
  return $meta;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: A better (not acf dependent) solution would be to use two different filters, one to retrieve the old value and save to a variable and the second to catch the new value and do the logic...

Comment: In this case: update_{$meta_type}_meta and updated_{$meta_type}_meta are the actions